# Has there been any bolide-spacecraft near-miss?

Tags: reentry, impact, meteors

Has there been any incident where a reentering spacecraft nearly collided with a meteor?

Comment: This sounds familiar. While not "close", wasn't there a photo with both a (distant) meteor and a departing Soyuz (or shuttle) taken from the ISS?